# Use of split_string in SWI Prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

On executing the following query in prolog :-

```
split_string("/usr/local/eclipse", "/", "", [H|T]), split_string(T, "", "", X), write(X)
```

The error is

```
ERROR: split_string/4: Type error: `character_code' expected, found `"usr"' (a string)
```

I am not able to resolve it. Please help!.

Comment: Which version of SWI-Prolog are you using?

Comment: Hi, @GrzegorzAdamKowalski, Thanks for the reply. I am using Version 7.1.26.

Comment: The first goal will split a string into a list of strings. But what is the purpose of `split_string(T, "", "", X)`?

Answer (score 2):

String variable in `split_string(+String, +SepChars, +PadChars, -SubStrings)` is intended to containt **list of charcodes**. In your example

```
split_string("/usr/local/eclipse", "/", "", [H|T]).
H = "",
T = ["usr", "local", "eclipse"].
```

So T is a **list of lists of charcodes**. That's why there is an error in the next part of your query:

```
split_string(T, "", "", X), write(X)
```

I don't know what your code is intended to do, so I can't propose a way to fix your code.